# Remove rows from an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a rather big table where I dynamically remove some rows. It works, but it is very slow. Right now it takes approx. 1.5 seconds to remove 50 rows on IE8 and Firefox (almost no difference between the browsers).

I know that DOM manipulation is slow in general, but there must be a faster way to do this.

Right now, I'm using this syntax:

```
$("#myTable tr").slice(250, 300).remove();
```

The offsets in the `slice()` method may vary. I use `slice()` since this was recommended in jQuerys help and other methods to perform the same thing - like `find()` or `eq()` - where not faster. I read about doing an `empty()` before the removal, but that was even slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the actual javascript, in case jQuery is triggering render refreshes: http://jsfiddle.net/MbXX5/

```
var removeRows = function(ofTable,from,to) {
    for(var row=to; row>=from; --row) {
        ofTable.deleteRow(row);
    }
};
```

As you can see in the jsfiddle, this is instant. Note that I'm traversing the array in reverse, so that the row numbers remain correct. There is a chance this improves the performance, depending on the DOM code and the JIT strategies the browser uses.

[Edit: new jsfiddle with colour-coded cells to make it really obvious which rows have gone]

Comment: This was much faster in IE (row removal took only 160 ms), but much slower in Firefox (2.5 sec). This is weird :) I actually wanted to avoid a browser detection, but the differences are siginificant. Still it would be good to have a fast row removal in Firefox.

Comment: In my Firefox (13.0) it was instant, as it was in Chrome. Not sure what's going on with that version of Firefox of yours...

Comment: I used Firefox 15.0.1 and reproduced it once again, no difference.

Comment: Do you have firebug running? It will disable JIT to permit debugging, which slows everything down enormously.

Comment: No, I just had plain `alert()` statements to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that for every row that you .remove(), the table is redrawn by the browser. To make it faster, remove the table from the DOM, take out the lines and put the table back at its place.

```
$table = $("#myTable").clone(true,true);//First true to keep events, second true to deepcopy childs too. Remove it if you do not need it to make it faster.
$table.find("tr").slice(250,300);remove();
$("#myTable").replaceWith($table);
```

Comment: This is faster in Firefox, saves approx. 800 ms. Great! However it is much slower in IE, row removal took 3.5 seconds there. So I guess I'll do a combination of your answer and the one from @Phil H.

Comment: If you know, at DOM insertion time, the parts of the table that will be taken off, group them in tbodys and remove the tbody. This way there is only one Manip. Using this idea, if you know that they will be removed by groups of let's say 10, then make one tbody for every ten? I have used a similar thing for an infinite scrolling script, was working great.

Comment: I really like this idea. My task is also pretty much the same, an (almost) infinite table where I manipulate the rows dynamically based on the scrolling position. By removing the `tbody` instead of all the rows I was able to reduce the removal time to 220 ms (Firefox) and 600 ms (IE). This is also perfectly valid HTML and improves readability (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter but I don't think it will be faster

```
$("#myTable tr").filter(function(index){
     return index > 250 && index < 300;
).remove();
```

Comment: While this is indeed a bit faster in IE (< 100 ms) there's no difference in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the browser tries to update the screen view of the DOM on each row removal.

You can do it by one of

- removing the table, from the document, removing all rows and after
  that inserting it back
- cloning the table, removing elements on the clone, replacing the table with the clone
- or if the amount of rows remaining is less than the ones remove, you could create a new table, insert all the rows in that and replace the existing table with the new one

The main idea is for the table to not be attached to the DOM when you do the removals, this way it will only update the view once all the rows are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you add an ID to each row? And then select the rows directly by ID and removing the rows? Like so:

```
var el = document.GetElementById("RowID_1");
document.removeChild(el);
```

jQuery is on top of Javascript. I guess using javascript directly is faster.

edit:
Ofcourse you can create a loop like this:

```
for(i=250;i<=300;i++)
{
    var el = document.GetElementById("RowID_" + i);
    document.removeChild(el);  
}
```

edit 2:
Hide the table while editing so the browser does not update after each removal ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this . i hope it will help you

```
$("#myTable tr").slice(250, 300).html('');
```

Comment: No difference in IE. Firefox actually crashed.