# Change cursor to wait when running a lengthy JQuery operation

Tags: jquery

I am having a trouble display the cursor wait when I run a lengthy jQuery operation. What I try is

```
function foo(){
   jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');

   //lengthy jQuery sort/DOM manipulation

   jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'default');
}
```

what I have observe so far is that, it looks to me like when `onclick`, invoke this function, it take about 6 seconds (time it takes to operate the sort), then I see all the changes at the end. This make sense since I am still within the same JQuery call, but is there a way to force the cursor change to show to wait, then after the sort operation, and change the cursor back to default once it is done.

NOTE: The length operation is not an ajax call.

Comment: Did the answers help you out or are there still other parts you would like to clarify?

Comment: @Salketer: Hi I am sorry that I have reply, but I am a bit tie up with my other work, I will test this out tonight and answer tomorrow. Sorry for the delay (I am not usually this late in replying)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems good but the problem is that your browser "freezes" when starting to run foo and unfreezes at the end so you can't notice the cursor change...

Try something similar to what you have but using a timeout...

```
function foo(){
   jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
   window.setTimeout(someLengthy,1);
}

function someLength(){
   //lengthy jQuery sort/DOM manipulation
   jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'default');
}
```

Comment: On a side note, depending on your DOM manipulation, concider removing the parent node from the DOM, do the manips and put it back in the DOM. It will increase the processing time as the browser does not have to "redraw" on every modification. Here is my answer on a question about slow DOM manip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837737/remove-rows-from-an-html-table/12837856#12837856

Answer (score 3):

May be the cursor is changed but browser is unable to redraw it. Try invoking the long operation using a timeout function.

i.e. 
-write a function that will ultimately invoke the long running code.
-Write a function that will just change the cursor
-Put the code to run the long code with timeout in the function in which you are changing the cursor. The timeout can be as small as 50ms. Just enough to let the browser update the cursor.